# Number of products in row of product grid in page builder

Tags: magento2.4, page-builder

In default mode Magento 2.4.3 shows 5 products in a row when [showing products in the page builder](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/page-builder-add-content-products.html). Is it possible to decrease the number of products to f.e. 4 per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple – pure CSS:

```
/* Large devices (desktops, 1042px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1042px) {
    /* -------------------------------- Product-Grid ------------------------------ */
    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item,
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item,
    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item,
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item {
        width: calc(25% - 20px)!important;
    }

    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(4n),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(4n),
    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(4n),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-inline-end: 0!important;
    }

    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(-n + 4),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(-n + 4),
    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(-n + 4),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(-n + 4) {
        margin-top: 0!important;
    }

    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(5n),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(5n),
    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(5n),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(5n) {
        margin-inline-end: 25px!important;
    }

    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(-n + 5),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .product.product-item:nth-child(-n + 5),
    .page-layout-empty .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(-n + 5),
    .page-layout-1column .block.am-widget:not(.list) .products-grid .product.item:nth-child(-n + 5) {
        margin-top: 25px!important;
    }
}
```